# iCal invites sent to my Gmail address (which is also my Apple ID) get added to iCloud

Tags: iphone, calendar, google-calendar

My Apple ID is my Gmail address. I also use Google Calendar as my main calendar. But, when someone sends me a calendar invite from their Apple Calendar app, I don't get an email in Gmail, and it there's no invite on my Google Calendar. Instead, it gets added to the built in iCloud Calendar that I never use. This causes me to miss events that I need to be added to.

I tested this on my own, and "invited" another Gmail account I have from the Apple Calendar app - it sent an email invite to that Gmail, which I could open, click add to calendar, and have on that calendar. This is what I want to happen when someone else with an iPhone and iCloud Calendar invites my main Gmail to a meeting.

This never used to be an issue for me in the past when I didn't utilize an iPhone (but still had the same Apple ID), but now I am unable to receive any invite from an Apple user to that specific Gmail. It appears as though Apple recognizes the email address when someone tries to invite me, and instead of sending the invite to the email, just adds it to the iCloud calendar.

Is there a way to turn off this iCloud calendar from accepting invites, so that these invites can be sent to my Gmail as a normal email invite?

Unfortunately, switching to using the iCloud calendar is not an option. I know I can subscribe to my Google Calendar in the Apple Calendar app, and to my iCloud Calendar on Google Calendar, but I need these events to actually populate on my Google Calendar itself, not just subscribe so that I can "see them all in once place".

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which email address are other people using to send you an invitation, your Gmail or your iCloud address? Which is your default calendar (under Settings  > Calendar > Default Calendar)? If you have a Mac running an older macOS version, check this post: https://www.techjunkie.com/turn-off-automatic-calendar-invites-mac/ to disable adding calendar invitations automatically.

Comment: Thanks! The invitation is coming from a colleague's calendar app and being sent to my Gmail address (I've had them type in the address manually). My default calendar under settings is my Google Calendar. I don't have a Mac.

Comment: OK, that rules out the obvious :-) Which is the iOS version of your iPhone? Does your colleague use an Apple device (iPhone, iPad or Mac)? Is the Apple ID email address you use for your Apple ID account set to your Gmail address, or is the Gmail address configured as an additional email address (see https://support.apple.com/HT201356#alt to find out)?.

Comment: iOS 14.5. Colleague sends invite from an iPhone and iPad (swaps between them) on iOS/iPadOS 14.5. My official apple ID is my gmail address. I wouldn't mind changing my apple ID to an @icloud or something else if you think that might help!

Comment: Well, that is an important piece of information! Since your colleague sends invites from an Apple device, your Gmail address is recognized as an Apple ID, and sent automatically to your iCloud calendar, and no email message is sent to Gmail. Fortunately, this behavior can be changed as follows: log in to https://www.icloud.com with your Apple ID, open Calendar, select Preferences from the gear icon, select the Advanced tab and select, under Invitations, "Receive event invitations as: Email to <your Gmail address>". Save the setting and test again. If that works, I can add it as an answer :-)

Comment: That worked! I now receive an email that includes a .ics file and it shows up on my Google Calendar as an invitation. That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for your prompt help!!

Comment: I'm glad it works! I'll post an answer and would appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your Apple ID is a Gmail email address, and someone sends you an invitation from an Apple device, your Gmail account won't get the invitation, but it will be added automatically to your iCloud calendar.

Why? Because your Gmail email address is recognized as an Apple ID, and that takes precedence: the invitation is added to your iCloud calendar instead of being delivered per email.

**That's the default behavior, but fortunately, it can be changed to behave the way you want**, as explained in [this thread on Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5274780):

1. Log in to https://www.icloud.com with your Apple ID.
2. Open Calendar:

   [image]
3. Select Preferences from the gear icon:

   [image]
4. Select the Advanced tab and, under Invitations, check "Receive event invitations as: Email to <your Gmail address>":

   [image]
5. Save the settings.

Now you should receive invites per email instead of being automatically added to your iCloud calendar.

Comment: That worked! Drove me crazy for month.

Comment: Thank you, that worked and has also been driving me crazy for a long time!